# ASP.NET MVC 3 + SQL Server 2008: How to implement cache invalidation for 1000s of product pages?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I'm building a web application in asp.net mvc 3 and SQL Server 2008 R2. The website is all about showcasing 1000s of products and each product has a dedicated web page. Each product page HTML is generated with the data from corresponding row of product table. When a row of product table is 
updated, I would like to invalidate the product web page alone.

I'm planning to use OutputCache feature of ASP.NET. Here are two question

1. Does outputcache suits my caching requirement or is there any better cache mechanism?
2. What is the best strategy for invalidating the cache of single page when underlying table data changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OutputCacheAttribute` has an [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.sqldependency.aspx) property.

> A value that identifies a set of database-name and table-name pairs
>   that the action's output cache depends on.

More info in this [article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Cache-Exploration-in-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Part-1.aspx).

Comment: "database-name and table-name pairs that the action's output cache depends on." - Can I have "database-name, table-name and row-identifier" setup? This help me to invalidate only one web page cache when a single product is updated in the backend.

Comment: I don't think OutputCache attribute supports it. You will have to use SqlDependency directly and cache results yourself. Or look for other caching framework - Enterprise Library may be a good start

Comment: Is it possible to use Enterprise Library along with outputcache?

Comment: Yes - Enterprice Library can cache the data you load from database / service layer and OuputCache can cache the generated html.

Comment: Perfectly with you on caching data from database/service layer. My problem is to invalidate the output cache when something changes. Enterprise Library may not help me in invalidating a specific page output cache.

Comment: If you're caching your database queries than you can use a short timeout for output cache (depends on the lifetime if your data - eg. 1min) It shouldn't take much CPU to generate html based on cached data (in most cases it's the querying that takes most of processing time)